# How to get a failure file/excludeFromFailureFile argument from classpath for maven-pmd-plugin?

Tags: maven, pmd

The `maven-pmd-plugin` allows to get ruleset files from the local filesystem (with an absolute path only, which makes it unflexible to use) and from classpath which practically means for a multi-module project that rulesets are put into a separate project which is build by a Maven parent or aggregator to that it's available for its siblings.

How to achieve that for failures files which are specified in the `excludeFromFailureFile` parameter of the plugin configuration in the POM? Putting them next to the rulesets which are recognized doesn't work, the [PMD Maven plugin article on multi-module projects](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html) doesn't contain information (why?) and [google appears to redirect to rulesets on classpath issues](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=pmd+maven+excludeFromFailureFile+classpath&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=T3J3WdTNEoPVXry1rJgI) systematically.

Loading from classpath allows to be able to specify the resource once in form of a dependency and to be able to build at every level of a multi- and or hierarchical project structure - consider the following example:

```
aggregator:
- pom.xml
- parent:
  - pom.xml (maven-pmd-plugin here)
  - module1:
    - pom.xml
  - module2:
    - pom.xml
```

where I can `validate` and build the aggregator (which will run on a CI service), the parent and single modules with one specification. Using `basedir` and `parent.basedir` doesn't allow that.

It's possible to put the failure file in a `git` or other SCM submodule, checkout the file during each project root which one wants to be able to build (parent project and eventual aggregators of the parent) and synchronize them manually at every change. That's not classpath resolution and complicated.

I'm using `maven-pmd-plugin` 3.8.

Comment: I'm a little lost with your issue... can you provide your current config / layout to make it clearer on us? I'm not sure how your ruleset issues relate to your `excludeFromFailureFile` issues... Also of note, the "absolute path" shouldn't be an issue, Maven has nice variables to move around that such as `${project.basedir}` or `${project.parent.basedir}`. Sharing config between modules and machines shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @Johnco I provided an example in which `basedir` and `parent.basedir` won't work because one needs a property for every possible build root (aggregator, parent and module).